# Cannot match any routes in Angular

Tags: angular

I have two components:
•QuestionsComponent
•QuestionComponent

Inside app.module.ts I am defining my routes, here is its codes:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//Angular Material Start
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
//Angular Material End

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { QuestionComponent } from './question.component';
import { QuestionsComponent } from './questions.Component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoute: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'Question', component: QuestionComponent},
  {path: 'Questions', component: QuestionsComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QuestionComponent,
    QuestionsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the app.component.ts, my template is equal to `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` as we can see below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'New frontend';
}
```

The problem is when I go to the `http://localhost:4200/question` URL, it again redirects to `http://localhost:4200` URL which is a blank page, and in the console, it says: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'question' Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'question'`

Is there any problem in my code ?

Comment: "Question" vs "question". Paths are case-sensitive.

Comment: neither /question nor /Question work!

Comment: Just remove the first route: `{path: '', component: AppComponent}`, and it should work.

Comment: To expand upon @Amer's answer - this is because router uses first-match strategy, i.e. it will use the first use that matches. So you should use the most specific routes at start, and least specific at the end. Read more in the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer so I want to share it to the others.

The problem was the Question and Questions in `path: 'Question'` were written in `capital Q`:

so here is the fixed code in `app.module.ts`:

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'question', component: QuestionComponent},
  {path: 'questions', component: QuestionsComponent}
]
```